# Is it possibile to use PhantomJS like a mobile driver in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, mobile, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm using Selenium with PhantomJS in order to scrape a dynamic website with infinite scroll.

It's working but my teacher suggested to use a mobile phantom driver in order to get the mobile version of the website. With the mobile version I expect to see less Ads or JavaScript and retrieve the information faster.

There is any "phantom mobile driver"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "phantom mobile driver".

You can change the user agent string and the viewport/window size in order to suggest to the website to deliver the same markup that a mobile client would receive.